# Nested directives, scope inheritance, and watching values between parent and child

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope

I'm trying to setup a couple of directives that have a parent/child hierarchy and I'm running into some issues understanding how scope is handled with nested directives.  Ultimately, I'd like to have a child directive respond to changes in a parent directive's scope.  Here's my example which is also on a jsfiddle (http://jsfiddle.net/4rt3b/48/)

HTML:

```
<div ng-app='app' ng-controller='MainCtrl'>
    Radius : <input ng-model='myRadius' ng-init="myRadius=100"/>
    <parent radius="myRadius">
        <child  pi="3.14"></child>
    </parent>
</div>
```

JS

```
var app = angular.module('app',[]);

app.controller('MainCtrl',  function($scope){

});

app.directive('parent', function(){
    return {
        restrict : "AE",
        replace : true,
        transclude : true,
        scope : {
            radius : "="
        },
        template : "<div>Parent controller's radius is {{radius}}<div ng-transclude></div></div>",
        controller : function($scope){
            this.getRadius = function(){
                return $scope.radius;
            }
        }
    }
})

app.directive('child', function(){
    return {
        restrict : "AE",
        require  : "^parent",
        replace : true,
        scope : {
            pi : "="
        },
        template : "<div>Child directive's pi is {{pi}} and area is {{area}}</div>",
        link: function(scope, elem, attr, parentCtrl){
            // This works
            scope.area = 2 * scope.pi * parentCtrl.getRadius();

            // This never seems to trigger
            scope.$watch('parentCtrl.getRadius()', function(newVal){
                if (newVal){
                    scope.area=2 * scope.pi * newVal;
                }
            })
        }
    }
})
```

Here are my questions/issues:

1. There doesn't seem to be a way for child directives to inherit scope from their parent directive. I tried changing the scoping declarations from isolate to true, etc. but still could not reference the `radius` variable in the child's link function.  Is there a way to do this?
2. I ended up using the `require` parameter to share controllers from parent to child directive.  This seems to work, however, I can't seem to $watch changes in the parent.  Type in a value for `radius` and you'll see the area does not update.  How can I $watch changes in the parent directive's model?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out.  The watcher needs to be declared like this:

```
scope.$watch(
    function(){
        return parentCtrl.getRadius();
    }, 
    function(newVal){
        if (newVal){
            scope.area=2 * scope.pi * newVal
        }
})
```

Answer (score 0):

You can alternatively set up a method in the parent controller to receive the child scope as an argument as it is passed by reference. The method in the parent controller simply assigns the child scope to a property of its scope, ie. scope.child_scope. Then, keep the $watch in the parent controller and set scope.child_scope.area = scope.child_scope.pi * newVal (within this $watch).